# Python 2.x unicode & pymssql

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I want to **upload a string in unicode to my sql server**. I'm using python 2.7.6, sqlalchemy-migrate 0.7.2, pymssql 2.1.2.

But when I saved my object I got an **OperationalError** from **sqlalchemy**

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (105, "Unclosed quotation mark
after the character string '\xd8\xa3\xd8\xb3\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1
\xd8\xaa\xd8\xad\xd8\xaf\xd9\x8a\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x88\xd8
\xac\xd9\x87 - \xd9\x81\xd9\x82\xd8\xb7 \xd9\x84\xd8\xaf\xd9\x89\xd9
\x85\xd8\xad\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7\xd8\xaa \xd9\x88\xd8\xac\xd9\x88\xd9\x87
\xe2\x9c\x8e '.DB-Lib error message 105, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL
Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n") 'INSERT INTO...
```

With more detail I'm guesssing is from my Description value :

```
...\u0648\u062c\u0648\u0647 \u270e \U0001f38'}
```

I saw a big U and not u, the character is the [gift unicode](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%8E%81) just before, the "\u270e" works well and show a pencil. I strongly thing is because of the **8 values versus 4 for others**.
**But how to prevent this error ?**

The column description inside of my DB is a `nvarchar(2000)`
I'm using Using flask restful reqparse to parse the argument create sync  the object from the DB and save it :

```
 parser_edit.add_argument('Name',                                                    
                          type=unicode,                                              
                          required=True,                                             
                          location='json')                                           
 parser_edit.add_argument('Description',                                             
                          type=unicode,                                              
                          required=False,                                            
                          location='json')
```

Comment: Are you sure that's right? `\U` sequences need eight hex digits but you only have seven there. Also, you should post the entire query (i.e. no '...' please). Even better would be the entire stack trace.

Comment: I will post the entire query tomorrow, `\u0001f381` I writing wrong. I will check and edit tomorrow.